# Used Audio Midi Set Up to use two audio outputs at once but now am unable to control the master volume of my MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, audio, sound-volume, speakers

I am able to control the left and right speakers on my MacBook Pro in Audio Midi Setup, but the master volume is completely disabled, as in I can't use the keyboard or audio window in preferences to change volume. The only way to change the internal speaker volume is if I manually change both left and right speaker outputs through audio midi setup. Would greatly appreciate any help.

[image: Multi-Output Window]

[image: Built in output Window]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50298/53510